# Heroku Node.js DeprecationWarning: Using Buffer without `new` will soon stop working

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mongoose, mlab

why do I get **DeprecationWarning: Using Buffer without `new` will soon stop working. Use `new Buffer()`, or preferably `Buffer.from()`, `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` or `Buffer.alloc()` instead.** after deploying to heroku or using localhost:5000
When I run it using localhost:3000, it didn't give any error.
I'm having trouble in displaying image that I Get from mongolab. Server keep giving me 404 error only for image data. Is the buffer thingy the cause of this error? Because hte images image can be displayed if I use localhost:3000.

Here's my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "caretel",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "jws": "^3.1.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "~2.5.2",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "express-jwt": "^5.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.1",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: The "buffer thingy" is a just a warning. Why it's not working is anyone's guess, without including at least some code in your question.

Comment: `return $http.get('getproducts').success(function(data) {
                var arr = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (data[i].owner.toUpperCase() == auth.currentUser().toUpperCase()) {
                        arr.push(data[i]);
                    }
                }
                angular.copy(data, o.displaylist);
                angular.copy(arr, o.displayuserlist);
            });`
this give 304 when the page is reloaded or the first time u enter without login.
Refer my app here [link](https://caretel.herokuapp.com/)